# Stripe - Create subscriptions with a customer with PaymentMethod instead of Source (Token)

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm integrating [Stripe Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment) in our workflow, but when creating a subscription with a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) created with a **paymentMethod** instead of **source** I receive the error `This customer has no attached payment source`.

If I call in the browser `createToken()` and attach it to the customer in the `source` field it works.

We integrated **one-time payments** using the new docs with SCA that use `createPaymentMethod()` and not `createToken()`, so our customers are saved with `paymentMethod`, not `source`, like explained here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards-after-payment#save-payment-method

```curl
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
  -u sk_test_secret_token \
  -d payment_method="{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}"
```

Furthermore, in the [migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#elements) it says to replace `createToken()` with `createPaymentMethod()`.

In [Scenario 2: Charging customers off-session for their initial payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#scenario-2), I saw the following:

> To create subscriptions and charge customers off-session for their
>   initial payment, you need to:
>
> 1) Use `CreatePaymentMethod` to collect payment information
>
> 2) Create a customer using the ID of the `PaymentMethod` you created
>
> 3) Create the subscription
>
> 4) Set up error handling using `handleCardSetup` for authentication failures and `handleCardPayment` for authorization failures

I followed those steps. I don't create a `SetupIntent` (just like I don't create it in one-time payments and it works in these cases), and receive the error I said before when trying to create subscriptions.

**Is it possible to create subscriptions with a customer with `paymentMethod` instead of `source`?**

*(We reuse cards using the customers created with `paymentMethod` for one-time payments, so it would be very important to be able to reuse the same customer/card for subscriptions, without the need for the user input data in stripe elements or anything of the sort, because it would break our flow for reusing cards)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by including the payment method in the field [default_payment_method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method).

This field is described as follows:

> ID of the default payment method for the subscription. It must belong
>   to the customer associated with the subscription. If not set, invoices
>   will use the default payment method in the customer’s invoice
>   settings.

So I assumed that it would use the payment method I associated with the customer when not defined. It seems it is not happening, tough, so I needed to pass it explicitly (is it a Stripe bug? or creating the customer with `paymentMethod` doesn't make it the default payment method in the customer’s invoice settings? I will contact Stripe to make sure).

**Update (2019-09-23)**

I contacted Stripe asking if this was a bug and they replied:

> [...] With that being said though, this wouldn't be a bug on our end, rather
>   expected behavior.
>
> If you're wanting for the Payment Method that you're adding to the
>   customer object to be used on subscriptions, or invoices, by default
>   without specifying the default_payment_method when creating the
>   subscription then you would want to attach the Payment Method and
>   specify the invoice_settings.default_payment_method parameter when
>   updating the customer. This information can be found within our API
>   reference here:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach
>
> The parameter to use when updating this can be found on the customer
>   object itself, here:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method
>
> This can also be specified upon customer creation, which can be seen
>   here:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method
>
> Specifying this parameter would indicate that the card being added
>   would be the default for subscriptions, as well as invoices, so that
>   the default_payment_method wouldn't need to be specified upon the
>   subscription, or invoice, creation.